Нужны ли запятые перед союзом И в данных предложениях?
1. Поэтому и стало принято окна заколачивать, чтобы свет не привлекал внимания (?) и существа думали, будто в доме пусто.
2. В наше время найти еду не так-то просто, а они столуются здесь (?) и спасибо из них не вытрясти под дулом пистолета.

Правильно:

Поэтому и стало принято окна заколачивать, чтобы свет не привлекал внимания и (чтобы) существа думали, будто в доме пусто.

В наше время найти еду не так-то просто, // а они столуются здесь, // и спасибо из них не вытрясти под дулом пистолета.


Пояснение

Это СПП, 4 предикативные основы,  два придаточных цели и изъяснительное придаточное. Придаточные цели являются однородными, запятой нет. Союз ЧТОБЫ не повторяется, но он относится к обоим предложениям.

Это ССП, 3 предикативные основы, сочинительные союзы А и И. Нет причин для непостановки запятой, сочинительный союз А не может быть общим элементом, связывающим второе и третье предложения.


Примечание. Союз А относится к группе противительных союзов, но имеет собственное сопоставительное значение. Интересно то, что предложения в ССП при наличии союза А однородны, как и при бессоюзной связи. Поэтому нет привычного деления на два блока:  три предложения в составе ССП независимы между собой, как и при отсутствии союза.

Спасибо! Только я не поняла: в первом пункте вы говорите про однородность, поэтому запятая нужна. Во втором пункте снова однородность, только запятая не нужна (?)

Первый пункт понятен, он по Розенталю, пункт 3 http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139   Про второй  дополнительная информация, из грамматики.  Там общий элемент соединяет тоже однородные по семантике предложения,  без взаимной прич. след. связи. Но по Розенталю сочинительные союзы  не  являются общим элементом, пункт 2 http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133

Но можно ведь спросить, а почему? Про союз НО он пишет, а как быть с союзом А. Этот союз всего лишь сопоставляет ситуации, но предложения не объединяет. Так что все три предложения свободны и независимы. // Это как бы мое объяснение, если уж Розенталь не написал)
